# Как вытащить значении одной колонки в переменные

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, plsql

Есть запрос который возвращает данные в таком ввиде:

```
| ID |
+----+
| 25 |
| 28 |
```

Запрос всегда будет возвращать 2 значение
Мне нужно к примеру вытащить данные(25,28) значении  в переменную то есть в into
Запрос :

```
select  ID  from table1
where CODE in ('bonus', 'Pnlty') and dcl_id := iId
```

Пробовал через pivot

```
with BaseData as (select  ID, CODE  from table1
where CODE in ('bonus', 'Pnlty') and dcl_id := iId)
select * from  BaseData 
PIVOT
(
  MAX(ID)
  FOR CODE in ('bonus', 'Pnlty')
)
```

Но как здесь вывести на into? Нужен запрос наподобие:

```
select  ID as id1,
        ID as id2
        into bId, pID
into  from table1
    where CODE in ('bonus', 'Pnlty') and dcl_id := iId
```

Comment: можно в цикле записывать а так курсор в помощь

Comment: Можете добавить пример данных? Не понятно, что в table1.

Answer (score 3):

Если заранее известно, что результат всегда две строчки, то самое простое, связать таблицу саму с собой (*self join*). Как-то так:

```sql
create table table1 as
with t (id, code, dcl_id) as (
    select 25, 'bonus', 9999 from dual union all
    select 28, 'Pnlty', 9999 from dual
) select * from t;

declare
    id1 number;
    id2 number;
begin 
    select t1.id, t2.id into id1, id2  
    from table1 t1
    join table1 t2 on (t2.dcl_id = t2.dcl_id and t1.id < t2.id)
    where t1.code in ('bonus', 'Pnlty') and t1.dcl_id = 9999
    ;
    dbms_output.put_line ('id1='||id1||' id2='||id2);
end;
/
```

> id1=25 id2=28

---

PS Условие соединения здесь только для примера, так как в вопросе отсутствуют данные. Для реальных данных оно скорее всего будет выглядеть по другому.